# Diameter of an open ball in a normed space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

This is probably a silly question, but I'm reading some class notes that have the following proposition:

In general it's true that $\operatorname{diam}( B(x,r) ) \leq 2r $ but in a normed space $\operatorname{diam}( B(x,r) ) = 2r $.

The diameter is defined as $ \operatorname{diam} A = \sup\{ d(a,b) : a, b \in A \} $ which is the standard definition.

The proving the inequality is trivial, but I can't seem to solve the equality.
According to the text, we take a vector $v$ so that $\|v\| = r$ and then $x + v \in B(x,r) $ and $x - v \in B(x,r) $. From there we get that $d(x + v, x - v) = 2r$.

What I can't understand is why would $x + v$ and $x - v$ be inside the open ball if the ball is open.

I imagine there's an error in the statement and it was meant to say otherwise, but maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe B denotes a closed ball?

Comment: Take $x\pm (1-\epsilon) v$

Comment: That wouldn't be consistent with the notation it's been using, but it's a likely typo.

Comment: @orangeskid I think I get what you mean, but what difference does the fact that the space is normed instead of just a metric space make in that case? I can't see any.

Comment: In a metric space you can't do $(1-\epsilon)x$. Also,  norms are positively homogeneous.

Comment: Ah, the distance between two points is the norm of the difference. You have vectors of any desired norm if the space is not $0$, since $|| a v || = |a| \cdot ||v||$.  Compare this with a discrete metric space: $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\ne y$ and $0$ if $x=y$. So you see that an  open ball $B_r(x)= \{ y \ | d(x,y) < r\}$  contains only $x$ if $r < 1$ , and so its diameter is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a *non-zero* normed vector space over the field $k = \mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ then you always have a unit vector $u$ (that is, a vector of norm $1$) and then vectors $ru$ and $-ru$ have distance $2r$, so that you have equality indeed. On the zero vector space, the equality is false though, as soon as $r>0$.

But beware, this is false in general. Consider the field $k = \mathbf{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers, for a fixed prime number $p$, and let simply $V = k$ endowed with the $p$-adic absolute value $|\cdot|_p$. Consider then $B_F (0, 1)$ for instance, and let $x,y$ be in it. As $|\cdot|_p$ is non-archimedean, you have $d(x,y) = \|x-y\| = |x-y|_p \leq \max(|x|_p,|y|_p)\leq 1$, and the diameter will never reach $2$.

Answer (score 1):

you can take $∥v∥ = r - ϵ$ with $0 <ϵ< r.$
 Then put the question: $x-v ∈ B(x,r)$? well the answer is yes because $ ∥ x-(x-v) ∥= ∥ v ∥=r-ϵ < r.$
the same reason for $x+v$ .
then $ ∥ ( x+v)-(x-v) ∥=2r-2ϵ $ now you can take $ ϵ$ small enought to obtain that :supremum is $2r$